# Cache using PHP cURL

Tags: php, caching, curl

I'm using PHP cURL to fetch information from another website and insert it into my page. I was wondering if it was possible to have the fetched information cached on my server? For example, when a visitor requests a page, the information is fetched and cached on my server for 24 hours. The page is then entirely served locally for 24 hours. When the 24 hours expire, the information is again fetched and cached when another visitor requests it, in the same way.

The code I am currently using to fetch the information is as follows:

```
$url = $fullURL;
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
echo $result;
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write or download a php caching library (like [extensible php caching library](https://github.com/jleider/extensible-php-caching-library) or such) and adjust your current code to first take a look at cache.

Let's say your cache library has 2 functions called:

```
save_cache($result, $cache_key, $timestamp)
```

and

```
get_cache($cache_key, $timestamp)
```

With `save_cache()` you will save the $result into the cache and with `get_cache()` you will retrieve the data.

`$cache_key` would be `md5($fullURL)`, a unique identifier for the caching library to know what you want to retrieve.

`$timestamp` is the amount of minutes/hours you want the cache to be valid, depending on what your caching library accepts.

Now on your code you can have a logic like:

```
$cache_key = md5($fullURL);
$timestamp = 24 // assuming your caching library accept hours as timestamp

$result = get_cache($cache_key, $timestamp); 
if(!$result){
   echo "This url is NOT cached, let's get it and cache it";
  // do the curl and get $result
  // save the cache:
  save_cache($result, $cache_key, $timestamp);
}
else {
  echo "This url is cached";
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the logic. In the end i downloaded the pear cache_lite library and this seems to be working smoothly. Cheers.

Comment: If caching time-expensive content, consider fetching new content before invalidating the one in cache (so it doesn't hurt your server when 300 visits at the same time will try to fetch the new version). Just serve old version while new one is being downloaded. The same applies to cached SQL queries.

Answer (score 4):

You can cache it using memcache ( a session ) you can cache it using files on your server and you can cache it using a database, like mySQL.

```
file_put_contents("cache/cachedata.txt",$data);
```

You will need to set the permissions of the folder you want to write the files to, otherwise you might get some errors.

Then if you want to read from the cache:

```
if( file_exists("cache/cachedata.txt") )
{ $data = file_get_contents("cache/cachedate.txt"); }
else
{ // curl here, we have no cache
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Honza's suggestion to use [Nette cache](http://doc.nette.org/en/2.2/caching) worked great for me, and here's the code I wrote to use it. My function returns the HTTP result if it worked, false if not. You'll have to change some path strings.

```
use Nette\Caching\Cache;
use Nette\Caching\Storages\FileStorage;
Require("/Nette/loader.php");

function cached_httpGet($url) {
    $storage = new FileStorage("/nette-cache");
    $cache = new Cache($storage);
    $result = $cache->load($url);
    if ($result) {
        echo "Cached: $url";
    }
    else {
        echo "Fetching: $url";
        $ch = curl_init();    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        $result = curl_exec($ch); 
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo "ERROR " .  curl_error($ch) . " loading: $url";
            return false;
        } else
            $cache->save($url, $result, array(Cache::EXPIRE => '1 day'));
        curl_close($ch); 
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Nette Cache](http://doc.nette.org/en/caching). All you need solution, simple to use and of course - thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got nothing against file system access, you could just store it in a file. Then maybe use a script on the server that checks the file's timestamp against the current time and deletes it if it's too old.

If you don't have access to all aspects of the server you could just use the above idea and store a timestamp with the info. Every time the page is requested check against the timestamp.

And if you're having problems with the fs bottlenecking, you could use a MySQL database stored entirely in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I made a pretty cool simple function to store data gotten from your curl for 1 hour or 1 day off **Antwan van Houdt**'s comment (shout out to him) .. firstly create a folder with name "zcache" in public_html and make sure the permission is at "755"

1 hour:

```
if( file_exists('./zcache/zcache-'.date("Y-m-d-H").'.html') )
{ $result = file_get_contents('./zcache/zcache-'.date("Y-m-d-H").'.html'); }
else
{ 
// put your curl here 
    file_put_contents('./zcache/zcache-'.date("Y-m-d-H").'.html',$result);
}
```

1 day:

```
if( file_exists('./zcache/zcache-'.date("Y-m-d").'.html') )
{ $result = file_get_contents('./zcache/zcache-'.date("Y-m-d").'.html'); }
else
{ 
// put your curl here 
    file_put_contents('./zcache/zcache-'.date("Y-m-d").'.html',$result);
}
```

you are welcome

Answer (score -3):

The best way to avoid caching is applying the time or any other random element to the url, like this:
`$url .= '?ts=' . time();`

so for example instead of having
`http://example.com/content.php`
you would have
`http://example.com/content.php?ts=1212434353`