# Caching CURL json data from server

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to figure out how I would go about caching the data I am pulling from a webservce json file onto my page so that I do not continually request this data and bring down the server.

I currently am pullin the json data like so:

```
// jSON URL which should be requested
            $json_url = 'http://example.com/datastore.json?toolbar_id='.$persona['toolbar_id'].'';

            // jSON String for request
            $json_string = '[Json string? What is this]';

            // Initializing curl
            $ch = curl_init( $json_url );

            // Configuring curl options
            $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
            );

            // Setting curl options
            curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

            // Getting results
            $result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string                
            $result = json_decode($result, true);               
            $result = $result[0];
```

From here I can pull the associative array results as I need them.  But If I were to refresh the page, it would recall the server info.  Any solutions?

Comment: You'll need to cache the result from the curl query. This is answered is more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978427/cache-using-php-curl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd treat it like any other cache file:

- Check if the cache file exists
- If it does, check the `filemtime()` against the current `time()`
- If it needs to be refreshed, make the `cURL` call and write the data to the cache file and carry on
- If it does not need to be refreshed, simply return the data from the file to to your variable.

It will be the same JSON regardless if PHP returns it via `cURL` or if PHP returns it via `fread()` on a cache file.

Comment: I should have been more specific in my question.  I am using a for each loop to pull multiple CURL addresses which are being returned in the form of json data.  If I setup a cache system should it be on a per URL or the whole page after its loaded?

Comment: You could do either. If you want some to be real-time and some to be cached, do it per-url. If they are all cache-worthy, then just cache all the results into a single file.

Comment: I looked into what I need more, and its variable caching. So should I still follow the steps your previously posted to do the variable caching?

Comment: Yep just think of a cache file as a stored result. Instead of telling PHP to "figure something out" you just tell it to "use the result from last time". With that logic you can cache anything, including queries, sessions, etc.