# How do I cache a JSON cURL response in PHP?

Tags: php, json, curl

*I'm pretty new to using cURL.* Is there an easy way to cache the response of a cURL JSON request? Here is my request...

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = "[JSON api call url]";

$timeout = 40;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));

$str = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$data = array();

if ($str !== false) {
    $data = json_decode($str);
}

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caching CURL json data from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977563/caching-curl-json-data-from-server)